# Multi-div text / link two divs

Tags: html, css, text

I'm trying to create a multi-div text. I have a long text and an image to insert. The image is on the left, the text is around the image. I'm using two divs. One next to the image and another bellow the image.

Something like this

```
#img{ height: 200px; width: 20%;}
#div1{ height: 200px; width: 80%;}
#div2{ height: 400px; width: 100%;}
```

I want the text to start on div one, and to continue div2. Any ideas?

Comment: I've erased it... But I want something like this...
`<div id="container">
     <div id="img">
     </div>
     <div id="div1">
long text
     </div>
     <div id="div2">
long text continues
     </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Are you getting the text dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

This is, essentially, not possible with current CSS.

[**CSS Regions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-regions-1/#introduction) proposed (as part of CSS Level 4) the ability for text to flow between separate elements.

At present suppport ([**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions)) is for all intents and purposes, non-existent.

If this is an absolutely requirement, you would need Javascript to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you want exactly, but try this,

```
#img{
  height: 200px; 
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
#div1{ 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 79%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... it isn't really the solution to my problem, but it worked for what I wanted.

## CSS

```
#siteawa{
height: auto;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#siteawa img{
height: auto;
width: 25%;
float: left;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="siteawa">
    <img src="images/logoawa.png" alt="awa"/>
    <p class="teli">blalbablba long text</p>    
</div>
```

They are both on the same div, but the text continues with 100% width after the image...

[image: example with this code]